# C# How to initialize a value (==null) inside an extension function?

Tags: c#, null, initialization, this

I have an extension function like

```
public static bool AddDict(this Dictionary<string, object> obj, Dictionary<string, object> to_Add) 
  {to_Add.ToList().ForEach(x => obj.Add(x.Key, x.Value));}
```

and want to build up the resulting dictionary if someone will use it like

```
Dictionary<string, object> test=null;
test.AddDict(oldDictionary);
```

I already tried

```
if (obj == null)
           obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
to_Add.ToList().ForEach(x => obj.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
```

as well as

```
if (obj == null)
      obj = (Dictionary<string,object>)to_add;
else
      to_Add.ToList().ForEach(x => obj.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
```

But none of the above worked as intended. In booth ways the test-Dictionary seems to be null. Is there a way to initialize the this-value inside the function if it is null?

Comment: Get rid of the bad habit of using `ToList` just to be able to use `List.ForEach`. You are creating and filling another collection for no reason, just to be able to enumerate the original sequence. You can do that already with a `foreach`-loop

Comment: Don't return `bool` but the dictionary, voilà

Comment: [first comment]
OK, this an option, too. 
I read quite a long thread here about how to get the best performance, and the statement above was the choosen one.

[second comment]
Cool, thats it! But I dont really understand why it works :/

Comment: Well, using `ToList.ForEach` is clearly the most inefficient approach. According to your last sentence, i've provided an answer below which also uses a generic approach, so works with any kind of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the argument to_Add as a reference, or changes do not affect test.
Althou, I doubt it does work on a this argument on an extention method. I suggest you return a new dictionary and assign test.

```
Dictionary<string, object> test=null;
test = test.AddDict(oldDictonary);
```

But the while things is a little backward. I'd rather use Linq function ToDictionary.

Comment: `ToDictionary` has a very different semantics. It creates a new dictionary rather modifying an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Your function gets *a copy* of the original pointer to the dictionary. This is not a problem when calling a function since the copy still points to the same element, but if you modify the pointer to a different instance (such as assigning it a new dictionary), this modification has no effect on the original pointer.

C# has a parameter modifier called `ref` that changes the parameter passing so that you can indeed change the pointer so that your first try would actually work. However, trying to do that, the compiler correctly amends `Error  CS1101: The parameter modifier 'ref' cannot be used with 'this'`.

So, either you raise an exception that the target object is null or you make the method an ordinary method. I would be in favor of the former.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!